# Rewrite template.js.erb into template.js.slim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

What would the below js.erb template look like when rewritten into slim?

```
$('#new_reservation').hide().after('<%= j render("new_reservation") %>');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
| $('#new_reservation').hide().after('
= j render("new_reservation")
| ');
```

you can check this [gem](https://github.com/slim-template/slim/wiki/Template-Converters-ERB-to-SLIM) for further simple conversions

Comment: How to pass the variables with new_reservation partial?

Answer (score 5):

Slim provides a multiline approach:

```
|
  var html = "#{ j render("new_reservation") }";
  $('#new_reservation').hide().after(html);
```

Answer (score 3):

lately I bumped into same problem

```
| $('#new_reservation').hide().after('#{= j render("new_reservation")}');
```

maybe for someone will be helpful
Rails 4.2 Ruby 2.3