# Rewrite js.erb file to js.slim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, erb, slim-lang

What would the below js.erb template look like when rewritten into slim?

```
'<%= form_for(@question) do |f| %>'
$('.option-partial').html("<%= j render(partial: @question_type, locals: {f: f}) %>");
'<% end %>'
```

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27158328/rewrite-template-js-erb-into-template-js-slim

Answer (score 0):

```html
| '
= form_for(@question) do |f|
  | ' $('.option-partial').html("
  = j render(partial: @question_type, locals: {f: f})
  | "); '
| '
```

Visit http://erb2slim.com/ for more help